# DNS Changer on my iPad

Tags: ipad, dns

I've jailbroken my iPad. First time I checked with dns-changer.eu it stated mine was manipulated, then I checked again it stated that mine is clean. Getting confused & curious, I checked again several times. Most of those stated mine is clean, but once manipulated again then clean while I rechecked around 1 minute later.

I've 2 laptops at home, 1 is fine & 1 is affected while the site stated that both of those are clean. The affected laptop gets limited access through wi fi. Connection is pretty normal using LAN but yahoo.com is still firewalled. I've scanned the affected use HitmanPro btw.

Please help, is there anything I can do or I just reset my ipad? Thanks a lot..

Comment: What is your question exactly? Whether you got infected by a DNS changing virus or why you can't access yahoo.com?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you to confirm whether or not you are infected if you're getting inconsistent results from tools is to manually check your DNS settings against the rogue servers.  These are the servers that were used in the attack:

85.255.112.0 through 85.255.127.255
67.210.0.0 through 67.210.15.255
93.188.160.0 through 93.188.167.255
77.67.83.0 through 77.67.83.255
213.109.64.0 through 213.109.79.255
64.28.176.0 through 64.28.191.255

To check your DNS settings on osx, follow [these instructions](http://www.plus.net/support/software/dns/changing_dns_mac.shtml) to open your network settings, choose a connection, and then check the DNS tab.

To check your DNS settings on your iPad, follow [these instructions](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/452) to open Settings>General>Network>Wi-Fi and then check the DNS settings of your wifi network.

Comment: @Mint Please let me know if there's anything you'd like me to explain further.  If this was helpful, I'd greatly appreciate you marking it as the accepted answer using the green check mark next to my answer.  Thanks!